# Showing $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

So, my professor is reviewing Ring Theory, and he has decided to let $D$ be a square-free integer. Then, letting
$$
\omega =
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{D} &  \text{if } D \equiv 2,3  \pmod{4} \\
\frac{1+\sqrt{D}}{2} & \text{if } D \equiv 1 \pmod{4}
\end{cases}
$$

he claims that $\mathbb{Z}[\omega] = \{a + b\omega: a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D}) = \{a + b\sqrt{D} : a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$.

Now, I have no issue proving this when $\omega = \sqrt{D}$, but when $\omega$ is the other case ($D \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$), I have difficulty showing that $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ is closed under multiplication. I can show that $(a+b\omega) (c+d\omega) = (ac + db\omega^2) + (ad+bc)\omega$. Ideally, I would like to show that $\omega^2$ is an integer, so that the product $(a+b\omega)(c+d\omega)$ fits the form of an element of $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$, but this is precisely where I'm stuck since $\omega^2$ need not be an integer (consider, for example, $D = 5$). Any help would be greatly appreciated here!

Comment: $\mathbb Z[\omega]$ is closed under multiplication by definition. For a ring $R$ and an element $\alpha$ of a ring extension, $R[\alpha]$ is defined as the smallest ring containing both $R$ and $\alpha$.

Comment: I think the actual claim being made here isn't that $\Bbb Z[\omega]$ is a subring (this is trivial, as @Vercassivelaunos points out), but rather that the equality $$\mathbb{Z}[\omega] = \{a + b\omega: a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$
\omega^2 = \frac{1 + 2\sqrt D + D}{4}\\
= \frac{2+2\sqrt D + D - 1}{4}\\
= \omega + \frac{D-1}4
$$
where the final fraction is an integer as long as $D \equiv_4 1$.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't too hard to show that

$$(a+b\omega)(c+d\omega)=\frac{1}{4}(2a+b+b\sqrt{D})(d+2c+d\sqrt{D})$$